# How to Add value in 2D List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why i can't add value in my 2D List?  i try below but no work??

```
   public List<Material> Pantsmaterial;

   public List<Material[]> PantMMMM;

   private void Awake()
   {
       PantMMMM = new List<Material[]> { 
        { Pantsmaterial[0], Pantsmaterial[1] } ,
        { Pantsmaterial[0], Pantsmaterial[1] }
       };

   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must explicitly create new arrays within.

```
PantMMMM = new List<Material[]>() {
    new Material[] { Pantsmaterial[0], Pantsmaterial[1] },
    new Material[] { Pantsmaterial[0], Pantsmaterial[1] },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your list as below and read about [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) for more.

```
private void Awake()
{
    PantMMMM = new List<Material[]>
    {
        new Material[]  { Pantsmaterial[0], Pantsmaterial[1] } ,
        new Material[]  { Pantsmaterial[0], Pantsmaterial[1] }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simply `List.Add`:

```cs
private void Awake()
{
    PantMMMM.Add(new Material[] {Pantsmaterial[0], Pantsmaterial[1]});
    PantMMMM.Add(new Material[] {Pantsmaterial[0], Pantsmaterial[1]});
}
```